# How can i check if google API is authenticated/authorized with OAuth2 using Node?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

Sorry if this isn't worded correctly I am very new to Node and to GoogleAPI.

I have an app with a button to login/authorize GoogleAPI through OAuth 2.0 so that I can add events to the calendar.

This all works perfectly fine. I can successfully login and add events to the calendar. I will add my code for this at the end in case it is relevant.

My trouble is that I would like to run a check on the GET request of the page that has the button to check if the GoogleAPI is connected/authorized so that I can show the button and give a warning to log in/authorize if it is not, and to hide the button if it is.

For the life of me, I have not been able to figure this out, I've been stuck on it for days now and have tried many many different approaches.

I have read the documentation, but it is not clear and I don't understand it too well.

I thought maybe it has something to do with validating an ID token? But I'm not sure, and couldn't work out how to do that.

If you have any advice it would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is the code for the initial authorization that works fine in case it is helpful:

```
const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URL,
  );

  exports.googleAuthCode = (req, res) => {

    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: SCOPES,
    });
    console.log('authURL: ',authUrl)
    res.redirect(authUrl);


  }

  exports.googleRedirect = async (req, res) => {

    const code = req.query.code;

    const {tokens} = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code)
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
    req.session.tokens = tokens;

    res.redirect('/jobs?message=Success')
  }
```

In response to @DaImTo it does not request authorizaiton if it is not already authorized it simply throws the error `An error occurred: Error: No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set.` and refreshes the page.

Here is the code for the GET request that adds the events, maybe I have set it up wrong?

```
exports.scheduleEvent = async (req, res) => {
    
    const date = req.query['date'];
   
    let events = await Events.findOne({}).sort({_id: -1});

    events = events.events
      
    events.forEach(async (event) => {
      try {
        const result = await calendar.events.insert({
          auth: oAuth2Client,
          calendarId: 'primary',
          resource: event,
        });
        console.log(`Event created: ${result.data.htmlLink}`);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`An error occurred: ${err}`);
      }
    });

      res.send({
        msg: "Done"
      })
  }
```

Comment: the thing is if its not authorized your code should request authorizaiton.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but that doesn't happen, I updated my question above to add more context, would you mind taking a look, please?

Comment: Any special reason your coding this by yourself and not just letting the client library handle the authorization?   [Node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/nodejs)

Comment: you mean you need a middleware to "guard" your get request from schreduleEvent ?